# React performance inspection with printWasted

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to understand what `React.addons.perf.printWasted` is trying to tell me about the RouteHandler component.  I start the capture, transition to page, stop the capture and check the `printWasted` and see this as our biggest waste.

`0  "AppTemplate > RouteHandler"    172.6510003209114   11`

We are using `ReactRouter` 0.13 and are still using the `Router.RouteHandler` to handle our routes and it looks like RouteHandler is taking its sweet time and not really rendering anything.

Is this a problem with `ReactRouter` or is this literally the Page that's being bootstrapped into the `RouteHandler`?  Meaning, is this something I should fix in my component?  Perhaps too much time doing other things before rendering the component?

Thanks.